# Using Nextcloud on the command line

Tags: command-line, nextcloud

I would like to know how to use the command line version of nextcloud as described here: https://docs.nextcloud.com/desktop/2.6/advancedusage.html

The problem is, that I cannot find the nextcloudcmd program. Downloading the desktop client results in an AppImage for Linux, but also if I extract it there is no nextcloudcmd program included. Is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation for version 3.2 says:

```sh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nextcloud-devs/client
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install nextcloud-client
```